# Green lines on playing videos in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: 19.04

Green lines of playing videos Ubuntu 19.04? L the native video player in Ubuntu is showing green lines but audio is working fine;? Installed codecs still doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just run the following in terminal:

```
sudo apt remove gstreamer1.0-vaapi
```

The gstreamer1.0-vaapi is the culprit.